# Split linked list into two other lists, one with odd indices the other one with even indices

Tags: c, linked-list

The question asked to write a function split() that copies the contents of a linked list into two other linked lists. The function copies nodes with even indices (0,2,etc)to EvenList and nodes with odd indices to oddList. The original linked list should not be modified. Assume that evenlist and oddlist will be passed into the function as empty lists  (*ptrEvenList = *ptrOddList = NULL).

In my program it can show the initial list. While there is something wrong with the other two list. And it causes the terminating of the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 9
```

// define the structure of of the list of nodes

```
typedef struct node{
    int item;
    struct node *next;
}ListNode;
```

//call functions

```
int search(ListNode *head,int value);
void printNode(ListNode *head);
void split(ListNode *head,ListNode **OddList,ListNode **EvenList);
```

//main function

```
int main(){
    ListNode *head=NULL;
    ListNode *temp;
    ListNode *OddList=NULL;
    ListNode *EvenList=NULL;
```

//in the question, it asked me to pass two empty lists to the function 'slipt'

```
    int ar[SIZE]={1,3,5,2,4,6,19,16,7};
    int value=0;
    int i;

    head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    temp=head;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        temp->item=ar[i];
        if(i==(SIZE-1))  //last item
            break;
        temp->next=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp->next=NULL;
    printf("Current list:");
    printNode(head);

    split(head,&OddList,&EvenList);


return 0;
}
```

****!!!!!!!!!
the problem I think is in this part.

```
void split(ListNode *head,ListNode **ptrOddList,ListNode **ptrEvenList){
    int remainder;
    ListNode *tempO,*tempE,*temp;



    if (head==NULL)
        return;
    else{
        temp=head;

        *ptrOddList=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        *ptrEvenList=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

        tempO=*ptrOddList;
        tempE=*ptrEvenList;

        while(temp!=NULL){
            remainder=temp->item%2;

            if(remainder==0){
                tempE->next=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                tempE->item=temp->item;
                tempE=tempE->next;
            }
            else{
                tempO->next=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                tempO->item=temp->item;
                tempO=tempO->next;
            }
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        tempE=NULL;
        tempO=NULL;
```

// I also tried `tempE->next=NULL;` and `tempO->next=NULL`
//the program can run if I modify it like above, but the last two numbers shown will be two random numbers.

```
        printf("Even List:");
        printNode((*ptrEvenList));
        printf("Odd List:");
        printNode((*ptrOddList));
    }
}
```

---

//function used to print out the results

```
void printNode(ListNode *head){
    if (head==NULL)
        return;
    while(head!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",head->item);
        head=head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Please narrow it down, nobody will read that much code

Answer (score 1):

```
void split(ListNode *head, ListNode **ptrOddList, ListNode **ptrEvenList){

    for( ; head ;  head= head->next) {
        ListNode *temp;

        temp = malloc(sizeof *temp );
        memcpy (temp, head, sizeof *temp);

        if (temp->item %2) { *ptrOddList = temp; ptrOddList = &temp->next;}
        else  { *ptrEvenList = temp; ptrEvenList = &temp->next;}
        }

    *ptrOddList = NULL;
    *ptrEvenList = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I cannot follow you. what does `ptrOddList = &temp->next`mean? Is it the same as`*ptrOddList = temp->next`? And at the end, what is the meaning of `*ptrOddList = NULL`? If I make it empty how can I print out the list? I think I still need a temperate pointer to create the new list. And actually I fixed the problem. While, the function is sophisticated... I'll try to improve it.

Comment: I attached my function in the following answer :)

Comment: ptrOddList is a pointer to pointer. So it should point to a pointer. temp->next is a pointer. So `ptrOddList = &temp->next` assigns to ptrOddList, making it point to temp->next.

Answer (score 0):

You're always allocating your nodes one step too early. Notice that at the beginning you're always allocating one node for both lists -- but what if there are no odd numbers in the list? Then your list is already too long at this point. You keep doing this every time you allocate a new node.

What you need to do is to keep a pointer to a *pointer* to a node for each list. This would be a pointer to the "next" pointer of the last node in the list, or the pointer to the head of the list if the list is empty. The next pointers, and the list pointers, should all start off as NULL.

When you allocate a new node, set the last "next" pointer to point to your new node, using your pointer-to-pointer-to-node.

Comment: Thx! I fixed the program, although it seems sophisticated... I am trying to find a more efficient way and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
void split(ListNode *head,ListNode **ptrOddList,ListNode **ptrEvenList){
int remainder;
int countO=0;
int countE=0;
ListNode *tempO,*tempE;

if (head==NULL)
    return;
else{
    (*ptrOddList)=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    (*ptrEvenList)=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    while(head!=NULL){
        remainder=head->item%2;

        if(remainder==0){
            if(countE>0){
                tempE->next=head;
                tempE=tempE->next;
            }
                            else
                                tempE=*ptrOddList;
            tempE->item=head->item;
            countE++;

        }
        else{
            if(countO>0){
                tempO->next=head;
                tempO=tempO->next;
            }
                            else
                                tempO=*ptrOddList;
            tempO->item=head->item;
            countO++;

        }
        head=head->next;
    }
    tempE->next=NULL;
    tempO->next=NULL;
    printf("Even List:");
    printNode((*ptrEvenList));
    printf("Odd List:");
    printNode((*ptrOddList));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here the question is to split the list into 2 halves based on the indices. But I can see the implementations on the `values(item%2)`.

So in the list the first node should have index of 1 and second node is of       2 and so on.

Use a count variable, which sets to 0 initially.

```
int node_count = 0;
while(head != NULL)
{
  node_count ++;

  if(node_count%2)
  {
       //prepare odd_list;
  }
  else
  {
       //prepare even_list;
  }
  head = head->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void split(ListNode *head, ListNode **pOddList, ListNode **pEvenList) 
{
    int remainder;
    ListNode *tmpO = NULL, *tmpE= NULL, *tmp;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        *pEvenList = NULL;
        *pOddList = NULL;
    }
    else 
    {
        tmp = head;

        while (tmp != NULL) 
        {
            remainder = tmp->item % 2;

            if (remainder == 0) 
            {
                if (tmpE == NULL)
                {
                    tmpE = tmp;
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                    *pEvenList = tmpE;
                    tmpE->next = NULL;
                }
                else
                {
                    tmpE->next = tmp;
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                    tmpE = tmpE->next;
                    tmpE->next = NULL;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if (tmpO == NULL)
                {
                    tmpO = tmp;
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                    *pOddList = tmpO;
                    tmpO->next = NULL;
                }
                else
                {
                    tmpO->next = tmp;
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                    tmpO = tmpO->next;
                    tmpO->next = NULL;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the above code has been tested for many possible conditions of a list of integer